# Android Detect what caused the onPause

Tags: android

I am not sure if there is a better way of doing this but I want to detect somehow what caused the application to pause.

On one particular activity  that displays a tracking map if the user click back or home I want to stop GPS but if the screen goes off I want to keep the gps running I am also using a wake lock so it doesn't sleep (yes I know this probably should be in a service, but that will be v2 I'm running out of time!)

I am overriding when the back button is pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    wl.release();
    this.mMyLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    this.mMyLocationOverlay.disableCompass();

    if (mLocManager != null) {

        mLocManager.removeUpdates(mLocListener);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

but I can't find a way of doing the same for home.

Can anyone help?

Bex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the `onPause()` you can call `isFinishing()` to know if the activity is finishing for whatever may be the reason or simply getting paused. See the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29)

Comment: The problem here is that if the onPause is caused by the home button, isFinishing() return false, just as if a new activity is taking over so we cannot use this determine if that pause was caused by a homescreen button press! This is driving me nuts! Does anyone know if there is a reliable way to tell if the homebutton has been pressed?

Comment: thats correct, you cannot use this to know if the onPause was because of a Home button. may be you can register for a home button broadcast

Comment: @Varun that would not be enough, because it is also possible that another app can come in the foreground (if it receives an intent, for instance).

Comment: @Vincent Yes, exactly, the `isFinishing()` will help know if the activity is being destroyed or if its just pausing. This is not meant to be used to find the source of onPause(). From the OP's question its clear that the OP wanted to know if the activity is finishing or just pausing and hence the answer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

But first please check whether your logic that you have written comes to `onBackPressed()`. write some log to confirm that that part of your code is active

If i understand you correctly. You have one activity which has some view from that activity you have started another activity. But you want when you click back key of the latest activity some actions you have to perfrom in previous activity. If this is the case you have to write logic in `onResume()` method. Because as soon as you click back key activity on top is finished and your focus comes to `onResume()` method of previous activity. donot override `onKEyDown()` or `onBackPressed()`.

Donot forget to vote if you feel my response is useful for you.

Thanks
Deepak