# How to know which activity caused my onPause

Tags: android

Is there a way to know which activity put my current activity on pause? I mean if my onpause is called, how do I know the activity that is becoming the current which caused the onpause to be called?

Thanks

Comment: whenever you move from activity to another, you put the previous activity in `onPause` mode. to check it you can add a `Logcat` statement in your `onPause` and move to other activities to check it. hope I got your question write

Answer (score 1):

If the activity is outside of your application is very unlikely that you will be able to know which activity was the one that caused it, however, if the activity that caused your onPause method to get called was one of your activities, you can find out by monitoring the "onResume" of your activities, the one that goes to "onResume" after your "onPause" is called, that would be the one.

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Comment: The problem is that I want to differentiate between admob interstitial and getting a phone call. Both causes my activity to go into onPause

Comment: Yes, but phone call can be also monitored through a BroadcastReceiver, that can give you a hint...

Comment: I guess :). I would've loved a general solution as I am more interested in knowing it's interstitial than phone call.. +1 though

Answer (score 0):

Get into the habit of adding the following line to every activity lifecycle method (onCreate, onPause, onResume, onStart, onRestart, onStop, onDestroy)

```
Log.v("LOG", "+++ <on...> <Your Activity> +++");
```

That way, your logcat will show you, in the correct order, the activity lifecycle and you will be able to see which activity caused your onPause.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The problem is that I want to differentiate between admob interstitial and getting a phone call. Both causes my activity to go into onPause

Comment: @Snake well If you get the phone call then it must be the phone call causing onPause to be called. Otherwise its admob.

Comment: I want to detect when admob interstitial is is the one causing the OnPause. As pressing home, phone call, many other other things cause onPause. That's why  was asking how  can know the name of the activity causing the the onpause so I check if it is admob and I I can do the rest of work depending on  that

Comment: @Snake Have u seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110544/android-detect-what-caused-the-onpause

Comment: Yea does not help unfortunately. In my case, isFinishing is never the case